# Products of HMTD decomposition

Tags: organic-chemistry, reference-request, explosives

[Hexamethylene triperoxide diamine](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hexamethylene_triperoxide_diamine), "Hex" for short, is an explosive organic compound.

I want to know the products of this reaction:

$$\ce{C_6H_{12}N_2O_6 -> ? + Energy}$$

Answer (score 6):

### Answer

[This article](http://energetics.chm.uri.edu/system/files/Oxley_ThermochimActa_2002.pdf) provide two reactions for the thermal decomposition of HMTD, depending on reaction conditions.

> (at or below 150°C, air or vacuum)

$$\ce{C_6H_{12}N_2O_6 -> 3CO_2 + N(CH_3)_3 + NH_3}$$

> (160°C to 180°C, vacuum)

$$\ce{C_6H_{12}N_2O_6 -> 3CO + N(CH_3)_3 + 1/2 N_2 + 3/2 H_2O + 3/4 O_2}$$

---

### References

- **Oxley, J.C., J.L. Smith, H. Chen, and Eugene Cioffi.** *“Decomposition of Multi-peroxidic Compounds: Part II. Hexamethylene Triperoxide Diamine (HMTD).”* Thermochimica Acta 388, no. 1–2 (June 18, 2002): 215–225.